# Insert a span after another span of a given textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text-box and a span with class star after this text-box. I want to insert another span after the first span of the text-box.

After validating this field I want to insert error message span after span class star.

With the following code, now my error span is getting inserted in betwen textbox and span class star.

```js
var v = 'Error message';
$('#group_name').after('<span class="error" style="color:#e03b3b">' + v + '</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="group_name" id="group_name" placeholder="ENTER GROUP NAME" maxlength="100">
<span class="star">*</span>
```

Comment: Try `$('#group_name + span' ).after(...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'adjacent sibling' selector (`+`) to find the `span` following the `#group_name` field:

```js
let errTextboxClass = 'foo';
let v = 'Value';

$('#group_name + span').after('<span class="' + errTextboxClass + '" style="color:#e03b3b">' + v + '</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="group_name" id="group_name" placeholder="ENTER GROUP NAME" maxlength="100">
<span class="star">*</span>

<input class="form-control" name="foo" id="foo" placeholder="ENTER FOO NAME" maxlength="100">
<span class="star">*</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#group_name + span').after('<span class="error" style="color:#e03b3b">' + v + '</span>');
```

Comment: Note that this would add the new content after *every* `.star` element